# How do I create app folders in the GNOME application menu?

Tags: gnome-shell, appmenu

Dose anyone know how to make application folders like the '*utilities*' folder? It's because I have a lot of apps and want to group them by topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in GNOME 3.38, allowing you to make and move folders in the application menu.

Answer (score 19):

### I. Native GNOME Method:

**(GNOME <= v. 3.32)**

1. Run Ubuntu/GNOME Software
2. Go to **Installed** tab and click in right-top corner button with "tick" icon
   [image] :

[image]

3. Select application to group in folder.
4. Click in left-bottom corner button <kbd>Add to Folder...</kbd> :

[image]

5. Type name of new folder...

### II. Not Native, But Most Comfortable Method:

**(need additional software, Ubintu <= v. 20.x, GNOME <= v. 3.32)**

I recommend to use [Appfolders Management](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1217/appfolders-manager/) extension by Maestroschan If You not familiar with GNOME extension, just follow link above and simple instructions. (You will need install recommended special browser Extension which help install this Gnome extension).

Use right mouse click on app and folder icons to get this options:

[image: add app to folder]

[image: edit folder]

Comment: I wanted to go with the native method, but some of the applications that show up in dash, are not listed in Ubuntu/GNOME Software. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @SaTa I had the same problem and had to go with the appfolder extension. It is very easy to install as it can be found in the GNOME Software, under "Appfolders Management extension" (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS)

Comment: Sorry, but this app isn't working with ubuntu 20, even more it's deleting all menu items! "Linux is free if your time has no value"! How to get all apps back? I don't know, uninstall doesn't work!

Comment: @user1660210 Thanks. What Gnome version are you use? I will fixed my post with priority on native method.

Comment: @mature thank you for the change. Yesterday I reinstalled my system with newer distro, so I don't know what version Gnome I had, but it was probably 3.36

Answer (score 13):

You can do this using a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called "[Appfolders Management extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1217/appfolders-manager/)".

It's

> An easy way to manage "appfolders" (folders in the applications view) directly from the applications view.

Right click on an app icon and you'll get the options:

[image]

Alternatively you may use an application called [GNOME App Folders Manager](https://github.com/muflone/gnome-appfolders-manager) for the same purpose.

Answer (score 10):

#### Ubuntu 19.10 and later

You can do what you do on your phone and just drag an app icon and hover over another one until it creates a folder. Then you can right-click that folder and rename it.

Comment: this only works on new versions of gnome and not the version I was using at the time.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It is possible with terminal.

I want to create a app folder named AV and I want my audio and video apps in it.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children
```

*Example:*

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children
['Utilities', 'Sundry', 'YaST']
```

1. Adding new entry "AV":

   ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "['Utilities', 'Sundry', 'YaST', 'AV']"
   ```

*Example:*

```
    $ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "['Utilities', 'Sundry', 'YaST', 'AV']"
    $
```

2. Putting `.desktop` files in `AV` folder:

   ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/AV/ apps "['audacious.desktop', 'mpv.desktop']"
   ```

*Example:*

```
    $ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/AV/ apps "['audacious.desktop', 'mpv.desktop']"
    $
```

[image]
It created a folder with required apps without any folder name.

3. Giving required name to the folder:

   ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/AV/ name 'myAV'
   ```

*Example:*

```
    $ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/AV/ name 'myAV'
    $
```

[image]
*You can rename the folder name at anytime

```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/AV/ name 'myAVfav'
```

*Example:*

```
    $ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/AV/ name 'myAVfav'
    $
```

[image]

4. Removing the created folder in future (or you can say go back to default):

   ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "['Utilities', 'Sundry', 'YaST']"
   ```

*Example:*

```
    $ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "['Utilities', 'Sundry', 'YaST']"
    $
```

Further reading: https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/AppFolders

Comment: This is a very detailed and perfect explanation, and it works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is very nice. Never thought this was also possible. Because I tend to pin down programs I use very ofter as Favourites. My setup looks exactly like Pratap's screen. I hardly find myself using the Applications Menu.