# How to group applications using terminal or configuration file?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, appmenu

In the "Show Applications" tab in Ubuntu it is possible to group icons together using the *create a folder* and then *add to folder* option in the Ubuntu Software (which is described in detail [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091972/how-do-i-create-app-folders-in-the-gnome-application-menu))

However, since I often reinstall my system, I was wondering if it were possible to do this **using terminal**, or by **editing menu's configuration file** hidden in depths of the system folders? This would automate the whole thing and save me a lot of time by not doing it manually.