# How to delete an empty app folder from the Applications view

Tags: 20.04, appmenu

the opposite of: [How do I create app folders in the GNOME application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091972/how-do-i-create-app-folders-in-the-gnome-application-menu)

I uninstalled all apps that were in a specific folder, and now the folder won't disappear.  How do I remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the folder's name! :)