# How can I delete Utilities folder in application menu?

Tags: appmenu

[image: Utilities folder]

I recall that I had used Appfolders Management in the past, however I can't do so anymore.

Comment: It is important to mention your version of Gnome Shell because changes have been happening here.

Answer (score 0):

get the folders with below command..

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children
```

Example:

```
[admin@localhost ~]$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children
['Utilities', 'YaST']
```

Remove the `'Utilities'` from the above output with below command..

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "['YaST']"
```

Exmple:

```
[admin@localhost ~]$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children
['Utilities', 'YaST']
[admin@localhost ~]$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "['YaST']"
[admin@localhost ~]$
```

How to take backup of the Utilities folder before removing it and further reading..

[How do I create app folders in the GNOME application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1091972/739431)