# How can I create app folders through terminal in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: appmenu

I guess that I need to use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children`, but how should I proceed? I tried `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "['Games']"` without success.

Answer (score 2):

You should give it a name and put atleast one desktop file name followed by your first command..

An example:

```
[admin@ADMIN ~]$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "['Games']"
[admin@ADMIN ~]$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Games/ name 'GAMES'
[admin@ADMIN ~]$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Games/ apps "['brave-browser.desktop', 'firefox.desktop']"
[admin@ADMIN ~]$
```

Once the above commands are ran, you must restart the gnome-shell or login back.. to see the changes..

Observe that the first one you gave `Games` is for Identification purpose and the actual one in the second command sets the name that shows in ShowApps/AllApps

[image]

Further Reading: https://askubuntu.com/a/1099604/739431