# How to merge icons of Activities from two pages into one page?

Tags: gnome, activities-overview

Now I have two pages of icons if I click Activities in GNOME, represented by two dots. Since my screen is big, there is no need to use two pages to hold these icons; one page is enough. Do you know how to merge icons of Activities from two pages into one page? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried dragging them to dot 1 page?

Comment: @PRATAP: I tried, but drag only pan between pages.

Comment: are you able to drag one by one of the second page icons into first page or not?

Comment: @PRATAP: Yes, I can do that. Is that the only way out?

Comment: there is a way with `dconf`, if you can follow the docs, you can figure it out. May be useful https://askubuntu.com/q/1091972/739431